# Confluence API: How to find out which css/js resources a pages uses?

Tags: java, confluence

We have an in-house plugin that exports a Confluence space. The space css file is already included, but this is far from complete. I've browsed through the Confluence API, but I can't find anything that will tell me which resources a page (including macros) needs to be rendered properly. Basically I need something that allows me to reproduce the following for css and js:

```
<!-- include system css resources -->


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/34/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css" media="all">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/34/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css?conditionalComment=lt+IE+9" media="all">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/34/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css?conditionalComment=IE+9" media="all">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/34/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css?conditionalComment=lte+IE+9" media="all">
<![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/34/_/download/superbatch/css/batch.css?media=print" media="print">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/4e59e07231dd67576ce6f003b6a8095e/_/download/contextbatch/css/page/batch.css?conditionalComment=lt+IE+9" media="all">
<![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/4e59e07231dd67576ce6f003b6a8095e/_/download/contextbatch/css/page/batch.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/75877fb710740f0fb2358dd832691580/_/download/contextbatch/css/plugin.quick.comment.pre/batch.css" media="all">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/767f156fe1e9f3d7a21cf551551d1dd8/_/download/contextbatch/css/viewcontent,main/batch.css?conditionalComment=lt+IE+9" media="all">
<![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/767f156fe1e9f3d7a21cf551551d1dd8/_/download/contextbatch/css/viewcontent,main/batch.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/62d979954d4d69b0a4870d806bfe4e43/_/download/contextbatch/css/atl.general/batch.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/1.3.4-SNAPSHOT/_/download/batch/com.jfb.confluence.plugins.latex:styles/com.jfb.confluence.plugins.latex:styles.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/batch/com.jfb.confluence.plugins.numcapt:styles/com.jfb.confluence.plugins.numcapt:styles.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/2.0.2/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.pagetree:pagetree-resources/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.pagetree:pagetree-resources.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/5/_/styles/colors.css?spaceKey=HELP" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/4.2.1/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.doctheme:documentation/default-theme.css" media="all">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/s/en_GB/3277/32/4.2.1/_/download/resources/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.doctheme:documentation/splitter.css" media="all">

<!-- end system css resources -->
```

Any ideas? This must be possible!

Comment: what's the issue with using the build in export functionality of Confluence > https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Exporting+Confluence+Pages+and+Spaces+to+XML ?

Comment: If you open a page in chrome go to the developer window (F12) and click Resources you can see all resources listed including scripts and css files.

Comment: @hovanessyan: There are lot of issues with the built in export functionality. But even if I could use it otherwise, I would still need to manually add the css as referred to above, as it doesn't get exported.

Comment: @user357320: There are few issues with that. First of all, I would like something that does that automatically, so that I don't have to do this every time there is some minor change to css or js somewhere in my setup. Second of all, that only gives me a list of the resources used for Chrome. As you can see, there are a number of IE-specific style sheets that I am going to need. I may have to do this manually after all, but I would really like to save my self the effort.

Comment: @boileau have you tried the Confluence AutoExport plugin? It exports the content to a static html so that it can be hosted on a normal web server, maybe it gathers all css files ... https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.confluence.extra.autoexport

Comment: It's not a very good solution, but if I really really needed to have the content to be backed up outside of confluence, I might just have all the pages built outside of confluence and then use the {include} macro. This way, when you update, the actual work you do is outside of confluence, and confluence would be displaying the new content instantly. It's sort of backwards from what you originally wanted though, so I'm not sure if that will meet your requirements.

Comment: @hovanessyan, I am actually using a customized version of the AutoExport plugin. Out of the long list of css files above, it includes two, so that's actually what I'm trying to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/Plugins/Theme+Builder) plugin. It's called Theme Builder and, if memory serves, it was actually recommended by Confluence in their documentation. I helped setup Confluence for my company and I really wanted to give this a shot but didn't have the time. I can best describe it as an IDE for Confluence. Like any other IDE, It helps to organize your files really well, and it also includes a GUI that makes it far easier to style your different pages so you don't have to type it in by hand every time.

I don't want to sound like a commercial, and they have a two minute video on their site (at the address I gave you) that is basically a little slideshow through their key features and does a far better job of exemplifying what it does than I ever can. I recommend you skip ahead to 0:48 seconds because that's where the features slideshow starts - what comes before that is a quick slideshow through some of their more notorious clients.

Good Luck! :)

P.S. Theme Builder is free!